# Python int too large to convert to C long in Python COM

Tags: python, c, idl

I have a python method that calculates value and returns it. 
The value is

```
CalcData = 3941269503L.
```

It is only 32 bit. Yet this is typecasted to long implicitly (suffixed by L) and when I access this method in COM in other application , I get the Python int too large to convert to C long error. I even tried typecasting it into int,but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "long" C type is signed so the largest positive value it can store is 2,147,483,647. The error is indeed correct, it doesn't fit.

Try "unsigned long" and "UL" postfix on the constant.

Comment: Yeah You are right, I dint realize whether it is signed or not